# Output Chessboard to Console in Assembly x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, chess, irvine32

I'm delving into Assembly for x86 and attempting to "draw" or output in my console an 8x8 white and grey chessboard. Still being new to assembly, I'm not having much luck :/ Wondered if anyone with more experience in Assembly Programming for x86 can assist and point me in the right direction?

I did one program before where I outputted a set 'char' in multiple back/forecolors, and that is where I cobbled together the below:

**EDIT**:
Updated Code when i figured out the colors issue.

**EDIT2**:
Updated Code to use a Loop as Gunner suggested.

```
TITLE Chess Board


INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

COUNT = 7
ROWCNT = 7

.data
    text BYTE "__", 0
    text2 BYTE "00", 0
.code
main PROC
L1:
    mov eax,gray+(gray*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edx, offset text
    call writeString
    mov ebx, COUNT
    dec ebx

    mov eax,white+(white*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edxecx, offset text3
    call writeStringL1:
    decpush ebxecx

    mov eax,gray+(gray*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edx, offset text
    call writeString
    dec ebxWriteString

    mov eax ,white+(white*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edx, offset text
    call writeString
    dec ebxWriteString

    mov eax,gray+(gray*16)
    call SetTextColor
    movcmp edxecx, offset text
    call writeString0
    decje ebxfourthSetTiles

    mov eax,white+(white*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edx, offset text
    callpop writeString
ecx

    decloop ebxL1

    fourthSetTiles:

mov eax,gray+(gray*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edx, offset texttext2
    call writeString
    dec ebx

    cmp ebx, 0
    je eigthRowTile


    jmp L1WriteString

eigthRowTile:
    mov eax,green+(white*16)
    call SetTextColor
    mov edx, offset text2
    call writeStringWriteString

exit
exit
main ENDP
END main
```

My current output is the following. I'm getting my 8 distinct "tiles", but would like and am now trying to find how to do so in a larger overall loop if someone can help out? to generate this output 8 times (with the mismatched tile colors)

[image: ConsoleOutput]

I'm trying to create an 8x8 grid in my console. Anyone have suggestions, tips, or ideas? Assistance as always is appreciated! :)

**EDIT3**:
Final Code

```
   TITLE Chess Board                (ChessBoard.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
; procedure prototypes:
SetColor PROTO forecolor:BYTE, backcolor: BYTE
WriteColorChar PROTO char:BYTE, forecolor:BYTE, backcolor:BYTE
PrintRowOdd PROTO color:BYTE
PrintRowEven PROTO color:BYTE

.data
rows = 8
columns = 8
horizCharsPerSquare = 2

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, rows / horizCharsPerSquare
L1:
    INVOKE PrintRowOdd, gray
    call Crlf
    INVOKE PrintRowEven, gray
    call Crlf
    loop L1

    INVOKE SetColor, lightGray, black ; return to normal color
    call Crlf

    exit
main ENDP

PrintRowOdd PROC uses ecx, color:BYTE
    mov ecx, columns / horizCharsPerSquare
L1:
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', color, color
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', color, color
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', white, white
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', white, white
    loop L1

    ret
PrintRowOdd ENDP

PrintRowEven PROC uses ecx, color:BYTE
    mov ecx, columns / horizCharsPerSquare
L1:
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', white, white
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', white, white
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', color, color
    INVOKE WriteColorChar, ' ', color, color
    loop L1

    ret
PrintRowEven ENDP

WriteColorChar PROC USES eax, char:BYTE, forecolor:BYTE, backcolor:BYTE 
    INVOKE SetColor, forecolor, backcolor
    mov al, char
    call WriteChar

    ret
WriteColorChar ENDP

SetColor PROC, forecolor:BYTE, backcolor:BYTE
    movzx eax, backcolor
    shl eax, 4
    or al, forecolor
    call SetTextColor       ; from Irvine32.lib
    ret
SetColor ENDP
END MAIN
```

Comment: It's been a while and I'm not intimately familiar with the Irvine include library, but `mov eax, something`, immediately followed by `mov eax, something else` is going to be unrewarding.

Comment: C'mon, don't do that, use a loop instead!

Comment: @Gunner, sorry, work in progress! D: Any insight for help on the looping?

Comment: All: OP has patched his source code, so his original problem is no longer obvious without inspecting his edits.  That makes the present "question/problem" rather useless, so it no longer shows the problem. I suspect this will now get closed as "too localized" since it can't be of use to anybody.

Comment: @Ira, Sorry about that. Fixed to show where the original issue was as well as final code. Was trying to keep everything easy to read and follow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the function "setTextColor", but one can make the educated guess that it wants a color in eax (the default place to place a single argument for called subroutines).

In that case, the sequence

```
   mov eax, gray
   mov eax, ecx
```

appears to load a color-indicating constant into eax, and then replace it with random trash from ecx.  That can't produce useful results.  You make the same error with black.

While color coding is nice, what you really want is an indication of the pieces on the chess board.  I have done this assembler back in the 70s (ouch!) using something like the following (OP to fill in necessary assembler details):

```
  White equ 0  ; tags a piece as "white"
  Black equ 8  ; tags a piece as "black"
  Empty equ 0  ; empty square
  Pawn equ 1    ; piece codes
  Knight equ 2
  Bishop equ 3
  Rook equ 4
  Queen equ 5
  King equ 6
  CastledKing equ 7 ; you need to distinguish this from an uncasteled king!

  ChessBoard equ $
      byte White+Rook, White+Knight, White+Bishop, White+Queen, White+King, White+Bishop, White+Knight, White+Rook
      byte Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty
      byte Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty
      byte Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty
      byte Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty
      byte Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty
      byte Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty, Empty
      byte Black+Rook, Black+Knight, Black+Bishop, Black+Queen, Black+King, Black+Bishop, Black+Knight, Black+Rook

   PieceCharacter byte ".PNBRQKk"


   main:
       call PrintBoard
       xor  eax, eax
       call Exit

  PutSpace:
        mov  eax, 0x20
        call  PutCharacter
        ret

  PutNewline:
        mov   eax, 0x0d
        call  PutCharacter
        mov   eax, 0x0a
        call  PutCharacter
        ret

   PrintBoard:
        call  PutNewline
        push  7 ; row count
    printrow:
        push  7 ; column count
    printsquarecontent:
        mov   eax, 4[esp] ; row number
        shl   eax, 3
        add   eax, 0[esp] ; column number
        mov   eax, ChessBoard[eax] ; get piece on board
        test  eax, eax
        jne   printpiece
        call   PutSpace
        mov    eax, '.'
        call   PutCharacter
        jmp    printnextpiece

    printpiece:
        push   eax   ; save piece
        test   eax, Black
        mov    eax, 'w'
        je     printpiececolor
        mov    eax, 'b'
    printpiececolor:
        call    PutCharacter
        pop     eax
        and     eax, 0x7   ; extract just the piece number
        mov     eax, PieceCharacter[eax]
        call    PutCharacter

   printnextpiece:
        call    PutSpace
        dec     0[esp]
        jns     printsquarecontent
        lea     esp, 4[esp] ; pop useless column count
        dec     0[esp]
        jnz     printrow
        lea     esp, [esp]
        ret
```

This should print something like:

```
        bR bN bB bQ bK bB bN bR
         .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
         .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
         .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
         .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
         .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
         .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
        wR wN wB wQ wK wB wN wR
```

Not particularly elegant, but readable enough to play chess on.
OP can use color changes instead of "b" or "w".

Comment: Thanks for the response Ira! SetTextColor is from the Irvine32 library: http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/source/irvinelib/settextcolor.htm. Would you mind taking a look at my updated code and offering some insight? :) As much as I like your code, I'm trying to learn some of this (and at this time, my end goal is only an 8x8 alternating tile grid, no chess pieces at the moment).

Comment: You appear to be roadblocks by with pretty basic things in assembler.  Suggest you read my code carefully to learn how it works; go look up each instruction, mentally simulate what the code does.  You don't have to use it, just learn from it.

Comment: I plan to, I was just wondering if you had insight for that single error so I could run it for myself :) Thanks in any case for replying.